# Slick2 / dyn4j render loop performance when iterating number of bodies

Tags: java, performance, game-physics, slick2d

I am drawing a series of Body objects on a Slick2D screen from a dyn4j World (World.getBodies()) and getting a very low frame rate, i.e. 6-10 FPS.  Here is the part  of the render loop in Slick2D that draws the dyn4j bodies:

```
for (int i = 0; i < space.getBodies().size(); i++) {               // Iterate through World bodies
    if (space.getBodies().get(i) instanceof lander.ShipFragmentPool.Fragment) {
        lander.ShipFragmentPool.Fragment fragment = (lander.ShipFragmentPool.Fragment) space.getBodies().get(i);

        float x = (float) (fragment.getWorldCenter().x * scale);    // Extract fragementco-ordinates
        float y = (float) (fragment.getWorldCenter().y * scale);

        float tempX = x % bWIDTH;
        if (tempX > bufferX          // Only draw fragments that are on screen
        && tempX < bufferX + sWIDTH) {

            float radius = (float) (fragment.getRadius() * scale); // Get radius
            float diameter = (float) (radius * 2);          // And diameter

            float drawX = (tempX - bufferX) - radius;       // Co-ordinates to draw on screen
            float drawY = ((bHEIGHT - bufferY) - y) - radius;

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawOval(drawX, drawY, diameter, diameter);
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing that the main issue that I am iterating over 36 bodies in the World object and having to test for object type in each case.  The returned Body objects are of different types and so I have to test each body to see if it an instance of the type I want to render (ship fragments after an explosion).  Is there a better (i.e. faster) way to construct this loop?  Or is there another issue that I am missing?

Note:

1. in the example above bufferY is fixed (the screen doesn't move when the explosion is happening)
2. bWIDTH/bHEIGHT are the width and height of the background image, sWIDTH is the width of the screen
3. I am iterating over a set of Body objects in dyn4J because I want to the individual explosion fragments to interact with the landscape, e.g. bounce, slide, etc.
4. the Body objects have a single Fixture and this is a Circle

Thanks

Comment: Move that outside the loop: `space.getBodies()`

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this:  
`List spaceBodies = space.getBodies();
    for (int i = 0; i < spaceBodies.size(); i++) {               // Iterate through World bodies
        if (spaceBodies.get(i) instanceof lander.ShipFragmentPool.Fragment)`  
And this:  
`List spaceBodies = space.getBodies();
    for (Object spaceBody : spaceBodies) {
        if (spaceBody instanceof lander.ShipFragmentPool.Fragment)`
  
Both perform at 7 FPS.  The second does not appear to recognise the spaceBody object as an instance of ShipFragmentPool.Fragment.  Sorry about format - can't work it out.  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it isn't the graphics drawing routine... it is the dyn4j iteration of the fragments during the `World.update()` method.  Changing the fragment Fixtures to sensors (`Fixture.setSensor(true)`) so they detect collisions, but don't respond to them, resolves the performance issues and I get about 130FPS if I run the game unchecked.  Shame, given that it's only 36 objects.  I didn't think that would be too many for dyn4j to handle... I suspect I am missing some setting somewhere to make this work effectively.  :/

ps. the `for (Object spaceBody : spaceBodies)` in my previous comment does work.  Not sure what happened there, but a clean and build sorted it out.